# Joomla: Protected content just below Easy Calendar

Tags: joomla

On this page http://bit.ly/13PplAT I am using Easy Calendar to show a calendar and whether the dates have been reserved or not. Is it possible in some easy way to show some content below the calendar that only the logged in users would see? The administrators of the site would just like to have some way of sharing notes about the reservations between them, and this page is ideal for them.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create two special menu links for [FARMHOUSE AVAILABILITY](http://www.thevintagecompany.net/index.php?option=com_easycalendar&Itemid=27).

The first one for people who are not connected (the current one).

The second one only for registered users with calendar and extra content.

Thus, it is just menu parametrization.

Comment: I have one user and he is super administrator. When I set the the new menu item linking to the Easy Calendar component he doesn't see it, unless I set it as public, which of course defeats the purpose. Also, how can I add that extra content beneath the component?

Comment: any further answers to this?